# What Technology is recommended to build a Resume Builder?

Tags: pdf, php, mysql, ajax

Good day,
I am about to embark on a project of building a resume builder. The builder will be interactive as it will make suggestions for the end user. I want it to be fast. I have considered using PHP/Mysql/AJAX, that would be great since I am expert in that field but its drawback is the PDF generation. There are not so many tools that help with HTML to PDF generation. The one I use (DOMPDF) does not give me the desired result for the perfect Resume.

Please, can anyone suggest the best technology to use or a better HTML to PDF library out there Or a better way of downloading auto generated PDF from website. The PDF is my greatest concern and has been since my years of working with PHP.

Thanks all as I await your responses.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. And note we recommend **software** here (which includes libraries), not technologies or approaches.

Comment: PHP/MySql/AJAX sounds just fine. That's how I would do it, unless I were an node.js guy.  Why "`HTML to PDF generation.`"? Is your code an WYSIWYG HTML editor? Even if so, I would personally generate the PDF from internal data, rather than HTML. Can you give more information?

Comment: AlL i want is for the user to download the Resume created in pdf without any changes to pdf (it should look exactly the same way as the browser version). So what do you suggest is best to achieve this, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to investigate a bit different approach for generating PDF from HTML. Instead of trying to find a perfect HTML to PDF library for your technology stack (e.g. PHP) try to take advantage of using Headless Chrome for PDF generation. We used this approach to implementing pdf generation for this [free resume builder](https://sweetcv.com).

For example, try to make use of this library https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php

But be aware that there're lots of other browsers (e.g. Firefox, IE, Opera) and you might face problems while trying to make your PDF files (generated by Chromium) look 100% the same as in others browsers except Chrome.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please I have begun with headless -chrome. I get this error ''chrome' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'. I hear you have to install chromium, but i have been on the internet and I have not seen any tutorial on that. Could you please help me on the next step to take. Thanks a lot for your time.